# How to take ALL the google calendars events for a particular day for my calnedar?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I want to take a list of *my own* daily events in a simple script in a linux terminal and return a text. The output should be something like this:

```
    (all day) Buy a pony to my neighbor's daughter 
    (all day) Douglas Adams birthday
    (all day) Battle of Mborore commemoration
    8:00am-8:30am take dog to church
    9:00am-11:30am meeting with Papa Snurf
    (...)
    6:00pm-11:00pm Python 4.0 meetup (free pizza!)
    11:20pm Lunar eclipse and end of the world
```

As you can imagine this comes from several calendars that I have in one web interface when I go to "today". It's transparent for me when I use either the android app or the web interface, but I couldn’t find an easy way to do this from python.

I was expecting to have  some iCal URL with some token from Google Calendar. But it seems it's not the case and I need some kind of OAuth2 authentication ( according to "easy authentication" found on https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/ ) like I'm doing something on behalf of somebody else (this is probably the most common use case for app developers).

Can someone point me out to a python full script that does something similar?

**Edit one**: after reading the comments I came with some code in Python:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

with open('my-app.p12', 'rb') as f:
  key = f.read()

service_account_name = '1....3@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
sub = 'MY_EMAIL'

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    service_account_name,
    key, 
    scope=['https://www.googleapis. com/auth/calendar',
        'https://www.googleapis. com/auth/calendar.readonly'],
    sub=sub)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http)

showDeleted = True

lists = service.calendarList().list().execute()
pprint.pprint(lists)

page_token = None
while True:
  events = service.events().list(calendarId=service_account_name,
    pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

service_account_name is taken from Oauth -> Service account -> Email address (under credentials in the developer console) and my-app.p12 was the secret key binary file  I downloaded when I created the app (I also have a text password from a dialog in the same process, but never used it. )

**NOTE: THERE IS A SPACE ON THE URL... because I don't have enough reputation in stack overflow**

**Edit 2: this is solved**

A couple notes: create a service account. Just like @DaImTo pointed out. I somehow missed some of the explanation he pointed out on the link

specially I missed creating the correct scope authentications for the domain HERE: 
https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients

Thank you so much for the answers. I wish I had more reputation to upvote some answers there.

Comment: Hi. In order for us to help you, we need to see the actual code that you wrote. Can you please edit your question and add any relevant code to it please? (make sure to obscure any IDs or other sensitive info)

Comment: This isn't a Ruby or Java question.

Comment: @theTinMan is correct. And after the edit is only Python . Tags removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse you are only accessing your own data I recommend you look into a [Service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  By giving the service account email address access to your calendars like you would any other user it will then be able to read the events without you having to mess with Oauth2.

After that its a matter of using.

CalendarList: [list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) to get a list of all of the calendars you have given the service account access to.  Once it has a list of the calendars it can then find the [events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events).

This should be enough to get you started.  Try searching for Ruby Google calendar api examples. Unfortunately I have no experience with ruby so cant help you with that.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's the right path but I'm doing something wrong. There is some python code on the **edit 1**. Maybe you can give me a hint. Thanks

Comment: Was a matter of reading the Service Account link you sent. I updated the question with the missing step ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consult these resources:

- An example Calendar API v3 program [(link)](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/calendar_api/calendar_sample.py)
- Google Calendar v3 API docs [(link)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads)
- How to create a client secrets file through the Google Developers Console [(link)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate)

Update: Try sharing your calendar with the user `1....3@developer.gserviceaccount.com` and see if that resolves the unauthorized client issue.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I've found them before but I feeling that the API was only for mobile/web-like apps accessing to others people calendar. I just want my stuff retrieved.

Comment: With the v2 calendar API (now deprecated and shutdown) your script could just use your username+password to access your calendars, but now you have to register a client and grant the client access to your calendars. Another option is to create a service account and share your calendars with that service account. Let me know if you need more details on that.

Comment: I shared with that email, and same results. I also notice that only allowed me to share the Busy/Free information. My idea is to get all the meetings I have for the day.